# Angularjs not loading using RequireJs

Tags: requirejs

Not able to load AngularJs using RequireJs. Please see the screenshot below

[image]

My AngularMin.js file is located under lib and index.html under web-inf . Can you let me know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your `main.js` file calls `require(['main'], ...`.

a) That's a circular dependency.

b) Nothing in the code you show depends on Angular, so there's no reason for RequireJS to load it.

Comment: :D , i just started with requirejJs and typescript ..anyways i did figure it out and now it seams it was a stupid question to ask , but anyways you can expect such things from novice